# Academic cover letter: My communications with department chair

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track

I am going to apply for a university-wide position and have already communicated with my target department. The department chair liked my CV and research a lot and strongly suggested I should apply for the position. But since the position is for the entire university, it is not clear if they have someone from the department in the search committee or can make any recommendation. So, I want to include this conversation in my letter. How can I possibly do this (professionally)?

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two options. The first is to just let that chairperson know you are applying so that they can make an informal background recommendation if they wish. I would guess that they will if the place isn't so huge as to make this impossible. Some places, of course, have strict rules about these things, but they will know what is appropriate.

But the second is just to write something like: "I initially explored this position with Professor X, head of the Y department, who encouraged me to apply".

Note that the tone implies that you initiated the contact, rather than just "Professor X suggested I apply" which is less proactive.

And, it is possible that both approaches can be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Let the department chair know you've applied and thank them for their encouragement.  They may/may not decide to  reach out to the search committee to say, *"Look at this person, I like them."*  Either way, leave it up to them.

I would not mention this previous contact in your cover letter to your application; I'd be concerned it might seem like name-dropping and a request for special treatment.